# What does the type foldMap :: (Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m mean and how to implement it?

Tags: haskell, foldable

Can someone explain what the type mean and how to implement this?

```
class Foldable f where
  foldMap :: (Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
```

Based on https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap,
they explained it as "Map each element of the structure to a monoid, and combine the results." but I don't quite understand what it means. How can I map an element to the structure of a Monoid?

I tried 
`foldMap f = mconcat . (<$>) f`
but I got this error:

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘f’ with ‘[]’
      ‘f’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the class declaration for ‘Foldable’
        at traversable.hs:41:16
      Expected type: f a -> m
        Actual type: [a] -> m
    • In the expression: mconcat . (<$>) f
      In an equation for ‘foldMap’: foldMap f = mconcat . (<$>) f
    • Relevant bindings include
        foldMap :: (a -> m) -> f a -> m (bound at traversable.hs:45:3)
```

I tried @WillemVanOnsem's code and got this error:

```
error:
    • Could not deduce (Data.Foldable.Foldable f)
        arising from a use of ‘foldr’
      from the context: Foldable f
        bound by the class declaration for ‘Foldable’
        at traversable.hs:41:7-14
      or from: Monoid m
        bound by the type signature for:
                   foldMap :: forall m a. Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
        at traversable.hs:42:14-47
      Possible fix:
        add (Data.Foldable.Foldable f) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            foldMap :: forall m a. Monoid m => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
          or the class declaration for ‘Foldable’
    • In the expression: foldr (\ x -> mappend (f x)) mempty
      In an equation for ‘foldMap’:
          foldMap f = foldr (\ x -> mappend (f x)) mempty
```

Comment: With the function `a -> m`. This sometimes is just an `id`.

Comment: You can implement `foldMap f` here as `foldr (\x -> mappend (f x)) mempty`. Note that a `Foldable` does *not* imply a `Functor`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I tried that but I got the error (edited in my post) instead.

Comment: you forgot to add `Foldable` type constraint in the signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> they explained it as "Map each element of the structure to a monoid, and combine the results." but I don't quite understand what it means. How can I map an element to the structure of a Monoid?

We do that with the function with signature `a -> m`. So we define the "mapping" function ourself.

A [*monoid* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) is an algebraic structure. It is in essence a 3-tuple *(S, ⊕, s<sub>0</sub>)* where *S* is the set of values, *⊕ :: S × S → S* is an *associative* binary operator, and *s<sub>0</sub>* is an identity element, such that *s<sub>0</sub> ⊕ s = s 
⊕ s<sub>0</sub> = s*.

Types that are members of the [**`Foldable`** class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Foldable) are data structures that can be "folded". It means that if you for example have a `Tree` that contains `Int`s, so a `Tree Int`, such that you, for a function `f :: Int -> Int -> Int`, and a neutral element `z`, you can derive an `Int`.

By using `foldMap` we will call a function `f :: a -> m` on these elements, and use the monoid function *⊕* to "fold" the values. For data structures that implement `Functor` as well, it is thus, more or less equivalent to `foldMap f = foldr mappend mempty . fmap f`.

We can however use the `f` in the `foldr` function itself, like:

```
foldMap' :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
foldMap' f x = foldr (\y -> mappend (f y)) mempty x
```

or shorter:

```
foldMap' :: (Foldable f, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
foldMap' f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
```

Here we thus first pre-process the values in the datastructure with `f` to convert these to a monoid object, and we call `mappend` as folding function on these items.

Answer (score 3):

So you have the following signature: `foldMap :: (Monoid m, Foldable f) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m`. Let's go step by step

#### The constraints:

a `Monoid` is data which can be combine by some operation. You can get many examples if you think a while. Just to mention here:

- `Integer` as data and `+` as the operation. The elements `1` and `2` can be combine giving `3 = 1 + 2`.
- `Integer` as data and `*` as the operation. The elements `1` and `2` can be combine giving `2 = 1 * 2`.
- `List` as data and `++` as the operation. The elements `[1,2]` and `[2,3]` can be combine giving `[1,2,2,3] = [1,2] ++ [2,3]`.
- `Vector` of size 2 as data and `+` as the operation. The elements `<1,2>` and `<4,5>` can be combine giving `<5,7> = <1,2> + <4,5>`.
- etc..

All of the examples above have a `Monoid` representation in haskell, tipically defined using `newtype` or `data` key words. In haskell the monoid operation is represented as `<>`.

An important property is that monoids have a neutral element and are associative. In the context of `Integer` under `+` the neutral element is `0` an associativity is given by the fact that `(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)`. You can easily find this properties in all given examples. Try out!

The `Foldable` constraint is easier. Essentially, you can summarize a `Foldable` data structure into one single value.

#### The function parameters

Code worths thousand words so...

```
foldMap :: (Monoid m, Foldable f) => (a -> m) -> f a -> m
--          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^     ^^^
--          |- We've seen this       |           |
--                                   |           |- A 'Set' of a's which can be collapse into a single value
--                                   |- A function to convert a's into a monoid
```

So by definition you can easily follow this reasoning/algorithim:

**Premises**

1. I have a Structure of elements which can be collapse into a single value
2. I have a way to convert this elements into a monoid's element
3. Monoids have a neutral element
4. Two monoids element can be combine together

**Algorithim**

- collapse elements of the structure by combining them using the monoid operator
- if the structure is empty use the neutral element as the result.

#### very fancy but... I'm still not getting It

The problem is that when you define an instance of `Foldable`, you haven't define yet how to fold the structure, and that's different for each one!. As in Willem's answer, you can define `foldMap` in terms of `foldr`, meaning that `foldr` is defining the way you can collapse your structure. Viceversa is also true: you can define `foldr` in terms of `foldMap`, and probably that's the gotcha!! if you haven't defined `foldr`, there isn't  a universal way to implement `foldMap`, It'll depends on your data structure. So as a code-sumary:

```
class Foldable t where
  foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m -- A default instance can be provided if you define foldr (a.k.a a way to collapse the structure)
  foldr   :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b  -- A default instance can be provided if you define foldMap (a.k.a a way to collapse the structure into a monoid element)
  -- but if you don't provide at least one, It'll be impossible to implement any
  -- because you aren't telling me how to collapse the structure!!
```

Comment: very concise explanation and thanks for including the definition of foldr